# Run command after system start automatically

Tags: startup

I am using ubuntu 10.04 and I want to run "gnome-panel &"  command after my system starts.Because my desktop top panel is missing when i restart my system.and when i m running gnome-panel & comand it is coming back.
If i put in .bashrc i m getting continously enter password prompt because my usrt is not in sudo group , can i put in /home/user/.bashrc or /root/.bashrc.Or can anyone tell me alternate methode to run command or shell script after system start automaticaly.

Answer (score 0):

Put your command at last of `/etc/rc.local` but before `exit`. Or add your command to `~/.profile` file or `/etc/profile` file

Add these lines (to give your user root access without password) to sudoers file (/etc/sudoers)  as :

Execute `sudo gedit /etc/sudoers` in terminal and add following lines to it at the end of `"%admin ALL = (ALL) ALL"`

```
user_name ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Replace user_name with your **user name**

Comment: hi freind, i dont want this user in Sudo group

Comment: Can i put this command in /root/.bashrc it may affect to other user also...

Comment: Okay dont edit sudoers file just add your command to ~/.profile file, it should work. e.g. gnome-panel . It will not effect other users if you put it in ~/.profile file , it will only effect other users if you edit /etc/profile or /etc/rc.local

Comment: what is /home/user/.profile , file i mean exactly what it is .what it will do and if i put gnome-panel &  ....command will solve my problem

Comment: Yes it should solve your problem,give it a try, it is the file containing information about a single user, the user who is logged in.

Comment: what about /root/.bashrc file?

Comment: read this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work , it will help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21774/discussion-between-khanthegeek-and-ubuntu99).